# "Real" VNC for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: vnc

I have Ubuntu 22.04 running on an RPi4b. I use the free VNC-Connect on my Windows PC. But I can't figure out how to get the server installed on Ubuntu.

I downloaded the Linux install file from realvnc.com: VNC-Server-7.0.0-Linux-x64.deb. But when I try to install it, I get errors.

```
sudo apt install ./VNC-Server-7.0.0-Linux-x64.deb
[sudo] password for p1:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'realvnc-vnc-server:amd64' instead of './VNC-Server-7.0.0-Linux-x64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 realvnc-vnc-server:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.3) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libgcc1:amd64 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libx11-6:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libxtst6:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If there is an install package for RealVNC Server, I can't find it.

Comment: Google "Realvnc Linux ARM" and you should see https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/raspberrypi/ in the results.

Comment: Doh! I was looking for the ARM64 and apparently clicked on the wrong one. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to install an amd64-version of the server to an ARM processor. RealVNC [download page](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002252798-Supported-Platforms-for-VNC-Connect#linux-0-10) has packages for RasPI OS 9 - 11. Download the appropriate one, and install following the [instructions in RealVNC blog](https://www.realvnc.com/en/blog/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-control-linux-machine-remotely/).

Comment: Doh! I was looking for the ARM64 and apparently clicked on the wrong one. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Been there done that =D Please do [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if this resolves the current problem.